# Blurring/Hiding windows when a timeout occurs

Tags: c#, .net, security

I have an application which has a timeout feature built into it, this will activate after a period of inactivity, and prompt the user to enter their password.

When this password screen appears, it is sometimes possible to still read some sensitive data behind this window.

Ideally, I'd like to hide or blur out the windows behind the password dialogue. But I'm open to other suggestions that might be relevant.

I'm assuming that I can iterate all of the open windows and either minimise them, or do something else funky to them to make the data on them unreadable.

Any ideas anyone?

Thanks, Rich

Comment: Is this a desktop app?  (Sounds it, given that you can iterate over the windows.)

Comment: What kind of app?  ASP.NET?  WinForms?

Comment: I guess minimizing might be not a good idea -- e.g. Win 7 with Aero remembers thumbnails even of minimized windows.

Comment: If this is WinForms, the easiest way is to literally `Hide()` all open forms, then `Show()` after reauthentication.

Comment: Yes, it is WinForms. And the forms will be displayed modally, so not sure if they can be 'hidden'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have achieved this with the following code...

```
        foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            f.Visible = false;
        }
        PasswordPrompt.ShowDialog();
        PasswordPrompt.Dispose();
        foreach (Form f in Application.OpenForms)
        {
            f.Visible = true;
        }
```

The 'opactity' option doesn't work, as the thumbnails still show the form with full opacity, which although virtually impossible to read, is not ideal.

@Ginosaji, if you want to post a similar answer, I'll grant you a 'tick' next to your answer, as your comment pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score -2):

Form.Hide() is the simplest solution for what you are intending to do. Actually, just setting the opacity to 0.1 will hide your form to the point that nothing but only a "ghost of an outline" is viewable. However, if you are interested in some aesthetic display, then you have to improvise. For instance, the below code will gradually make your form transparent, then back to opaque:

```
private void frmOpacity_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
this.Opacity = 0;
for (double i = -1; i <= 1; i+= 0.005)
{
this.Opacity = System.Math.Abs(i);
Application.DoEvents();
System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5);
}
}
```

If you are interested in more such ideas, then you can view my blog post:
http://dot-net-talk.blogspot.com/2013/04/some-windows-forms-magic-in-net.html

Comment: Agreed with @HighCore. And not only is `DoEvents` a terrible idea, you don't even need it here. You don't need to pump the message loop to make the form's opacity to change.